# Что такое "зга"?

Tags: этимология, фразеология, лексика

Есть выражение "ни зги не видать". Что такое "зга", и откуда пошло это выражение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раньше згой называли часть упряжи лошади, а именно - колечко, крепящееся к хомуту, через которое продевалась вожжа. Соотственно, если кучеру не было видно даже этого колечка, то темнота или туман были очень сильными.

Comment: Возможно, у слова **зга** появится новое значение. Существует современное словоупотребление:

> Передам - и не надо держаться в кругу
> 
> И в кромешную тьму, и в неясную згу

Comment: Этот не современное употребление. Это что-то глубоко "авторское".  
А если искать смысла в текстах современных стихов и песен, то можно легко свихнуться.

Comment: Ну, конечно авторское. Я имел в виду, мне известен **случай** такого словоупотребления (не совсем точно выразился). Ну, и уже не совсем современного, наверное. Но автор у меня доверие вполне вызывает (это Высоцкий), обычно он очень внимательно относится к словам, даже немного странно, что здесь допустил такую "вольность".

Answer (score 1):

Я слышал эту версию про колечко на упряжи. Непонятно тогда только, почему "ни зги не видно". Было бы просто "зги". А тут по типу "ни черта"... Воспринимается как ругательство.

Касательно же значения самого слова, не могу найти хоть сколько нибудь достоверный источник с подобной версией...

Вот у Фасмера.

только в выражении: ни зги́ не вида́ть (Преобр.), наряду с этим диал. стеги́ не вида́ть, тверск. (Горяев, Доп. I, 14), блр. сьцегi не вiдно (Потебня, AfslPh 3, 361). Обычно объ- ясняют из *стьга " дорога, тропа"; подробнее см. на стезя́; Мi. ЕW 328; Соболевский, Лекции 112; Шахматов, Очерк 220; Потебня, там же; М.–Э. 4, 681. Неубедительна гипотеза о первонач. знач. " искра", ср. диал. зги́нка "искорка. крошка", которое могло явиться новообразованием на основе выражения ни зги. Зеленин (у Ильинского (см. ниже)) ссылается на пазга́ть " гореть, драть", но оно значит также "быстро расти, стегать" и не дает основания для окончательного вывода. Ильинский (РФВ 65, 218 и сл., где литер.) пытается связать зга с поздним згра́ " искра", донск. (по Брандту (РФВ 22, 130) из* jьskra) и и́скра, тогда как Булич (Очерк 695) считает его родственным др.-инд. tḗjatē "является острым, заостряет", tējas " блеск", греч. στιγμή " точка"; см. Преобр. I, 246. Абсолютно фантастично сопоставление *зга с лтш. zaigs "блестящий", zaiguôt " блестеть, сверкать", др.-прусск. siхdre " птица овсянка" у Петерссона (BSl. Wortst. 51 и сл.); ср. М.–Э. 4, 681.

Т.е. зга - дорога, тропа. В крайнем случае (что отвергает Фасмер) - искра, отблеск. И то и другое объясняет и конструкцию с "ни".

Answer (score -1):

конечно, маловероятно, что латышское слово "заигс - отблеск" вошло в эту русскую фразу. А вот наше старое слово "стега - дорожка" вполне могло стать прообразом звуку зга. Получилось удобная звукокомбинация "низги": короткая. звонкая и понятная, как говорится "коротко и ясно".